Help me find title movie - us elections/mind reading
I need your help.
Back in 2013 I was watching a trailer of this movie about some guy that was taking part in the elections (not sure if it was for a senator or president) and he was able to read people's mind or something like that.
I think this movie was from the period 2010-2013 (but 2005-2013 is also possible)
I tried googling it with all kinds of key words like "mind reading" "political movies" but with no results. Hope you can help me.
Does it ring a bell to anyone?

Thanks so much for all your help, it was "Yetisasquatch Alienbeliever" who found the movie I was looking for:
The Adjustment Bureau
It was back in 2013 when I watched the trailer, so I was wrong about the mind reading part, it was actually about seeing into the future. (and it was actually not really that much about politics, as it was about the romance, oh well ;) )
Big thanks to all of you, you made my day :)
Have a great week! :)
PS. Btw did you guys like this movie? IMDB gives it 7,1. Of course I'm going to watch it now, but just wanted to know your opinion.

I thought it was good overall despite a few plot holes.

Here's the clip from the movie I mentioned in my comment. The pitch starts halfway through (about 1:12 through the video).
This is from Robert Altman's The Player and features a writer pitching the movie you describe to a studio executive. Since you remembered a trailer, not the movie itself, I thought perhaps you were recalling this scene.

This is probably not it, but in 1984 the movie Dreamscape came out and let the test subjects enter another's dream. One was good (Dennis Quaid as Alex Gardner) and one was bad (David Patrick Kelly as Tommy Ray Glatman). Kate Capshaw played Jane DeVries, Alex's love interest. They had to use a machine at first to enter another's dream, but each got to a point where they did not need the machine. They just needed to get close to their subject.
Ray was approached and assigned to kill the president (Eddie Albert) while in his dream. Alex was sent in to stop him. 
